# can the bowler from previous over continue this over?

Tags: rules, cricket, injuries

If a bowler gets injured in the over and has gone out of the field then can a bowler who bowled the previous over continue this over?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. This is very clear in [Law 22](https://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-22-the-over/):

> If for any reason a bowler [...] is incapacitated or suspended during an over, the umpire shall call and signal Dead ball. Another bowler shall complete the over from the same end, **provided that he does not bowl two overs consecutively, nor bowl parts of each of two consecutive overs, in that innings**.

(my emphasis)